# Different between move and forward in this example

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

The first example that take A by value does two moves and the one by refref only does one move. What is the difference?

```
struct A
{
  A() { cout << "constructor" << endl;}
  A(const A&) { cout << "copy constructor " << endl;}
  void operator=(const A&) { cout << "assignment operator" << endl; }
  A( A&&) { cout << "move copy constructor" << endl;}
  void operator=(A&&) { cout << "move assignment operator" << endl;}
};
struct C {
  void func(A t) {
    d.a = std::move(t);
  }
  struct Data {
    A a;      
  };
  Data d;
};
struct B {
  void func(A t) {
    C c;
    c.func(std::move(t));
  }
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct C {
  template<class T>
  void func(T&& t) {
    d.a = std::forward<T>(t);
  }
  struct Data {
    A a;      
  };
  Data d;
};
struct B {
  template<class T>
  void func(T&& t) {
    C c;
    c.func(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
};
```

Comment: This is pretty related explanation of "universal references" and how they related to `std::move` and `std::forward`: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2012/11/on-superfluousness-of-stdmove.html

Comment: as far as i understood it, they should behave the same in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward):

> When used according to the following recipe in a function template,
>   forwards the argument to another function exactly as it was passed to
>   the calling function.
>
> ```
> template<typename T> 
> wrapper(T&& arg) {
>    foo(std::forward<T>(arg)); 
> }
> ```

So in your snippet

```
struct B {
  template<class T>
  void func(T&& t) {
    C c;
    c.func(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
};
```

The `std::foward<T>(t)` will simply forward your `T&&` object to `c.func()` exactly as `B::func()` was called. This doesn't require a move, which is why you are seeing fewer moves using `std::forward<T>`.

I would really recommend checking out Scott Meyer's blog post on this topic of `std::move` and `std::forward`: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2012/11/on-superfluousness-of-stdmove.html